# Prove that $\tau (n)=2^r$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-set-theory

Prove that $\tau (n)=2^r$ where $r$ is the number of prime divisors of $n$ if n is a square-free number.

I was working with some numbers, i see that if $n$ does not divide $2$ then the statement does not work. So this is true only if $n|2$. any idea of how to tackle this.

Comment: Would that be this tau-function: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TauFunction.html? I suspect the ambiguity in not defining the function is what cause the single (so far) close vote (not from me).

Comment: I believe that here $\tau$ is the number of (positive) divisors function.

Comment: Yes that's it is. Tau is a number theoretic function that is about the number of divisor a number n has for instance $\tau(4)=3$ since 4 has 3 divisors 1,2,and 4

Comment: Imagine lining up the $r$ primes in a row. To make a divisor $k$ of $n$, we stop before each prime and say Y if the prime is going to divide $k$, and N if it won't. A divisor is completely determined by our Y/N choices. There are $2^r$ "words" of length $r$ over the alphabet {Y,N}.

Answer (score 1):

In general we can write any number $n$ as a product $\prod_{i=1}^r p_i^{r_i}$, where $r$ is the nuber of prime divisors, denoted by $p_1,\ldots,p_r$, and every $r_i$ counts how many times each prime occurs.

If $n$ is square free, this means that no prime can occur more than once, otherwise we'd have a factor $p_i^2$ for one of the prime factors $p_i$, and so $n$ would not be square free. So $n = \prod_{i=1}^r p_i$ in fact.

Now a divisor $q$ of $n$ can only have the same prime divisors as well (also occurring at most one time), and you can make all of them by, for each $i$, either choosing to include $p_i$ or not. So you have $r$ binary choices, made independently. So the number of divisors is $2^r$.